# Implement 3 table join

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have 3 tables

```
employees     
-------------   
|idEmployee |  
|   name    |  

user-employee   
----------------                           
|  idUser      |-> MongoID      
|  idEmployee  |-> FK employees.idEmployee    

employees-supervisor
--------------------
|    idEmployee    |-> FK employees.idEmployee          
|    idUser        |-> FK user-employee.idUser
```

I want the next table

```
idEmployee | name   | idUser | nameSupervisor
    1      | John   |     A2 |     Jane
```

Employee tables has all the employees from a company, user-employee has all the employees that are users of the system, the user-employee.idUser is the user of a mongo document and the employees-supervisor has a list that match the idUser (mongoid) with the id of the employee (mysql)

What I want is to show all the employees with their respective supervisor (if any), right now I get the idUser

```
SELECT employees.*, e1.idUser as idSupervisor, e2.name as supervisor
  FROM employees
  left JOIN user-employee e1 ON  e1.idEmployee = employees.idEmployee
```

This shows

```
idEmployee | name   |  idUser | 
    1      | John   |  5887Ab |
```

I already have the id of the supervisor, now how I match that Id with a name that is on the user-employee table?

Comment: Create one of these and post a link: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Don't use minus ('-') within a table/column identifier

Answer (score 0):

If the key could don't match the us can use left join

```
SELECT employees.*, e1.idUser as idSupervisor, e3.name as supervisor
FROM employees
left JOIN `user-employee` e1 ON  e1.idEmployee = employees.idEmployee 
left JOIN `employees-supervisor` e2 on on e2.idUser = e.idUser
left JOIN  employees e3 on e2.idEmployee = e3.idEmployee;
```

but if the key betwen the tables match you should use inner join

```
SELECT employees.*, e1.idUser as idSupervisor, e3.name as supervisor
FROM employees
INNER JOIN `user-employee` e1 ON  e1.idEmployee = employees.idEmployee 
INNER JOIN `employees-supervisor` e2 on on e2.idUser = e.idUser
INNER JOIN  employees e3 on e2.idEmployee = e3.idEmployee;
```